# Count Distinct from a subquery? Or another way to count distinct from one column?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

The final result should be The number os positions (type of jobs) active on that date, but since the clocktables have two entries per person (lunch time) the COUNT gives me back two results per person, it get one plus result if the person leaves or clocks a break.

FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47110d/1/0

Is there a way

I am trying to filter by distinct first but no happy results yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT
        positions.cargodesc,
        positions.cargoabrv,
        COUNT(distinct employees.employeeid ) AS npositions 
FROM
        employees
        RIGHT JOIN clocktimes ON employees.emp_external_id = clocktimes.EmployeeGUID
        LEFT JOIN positions ON positions.cargoid = employees.position_id 
WHERE
        DATE( clocktimes.StartDate ) = '2017-07-02' 
GROUP BY
        employees.position_id
```

Comment: Gonna try it! Confirm it Later! But so far Looks Good!

Comment: Correct! You sir are a genius!